# Kashrus of Sodium Alginate and Calcium Lactate

Tags: kashrut-kosher

I would like to ask if anyone has any information on the kashrus of Sodium Alginate and Calcium Lactate.

Do these chemicals require a hechsher or certification?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, welcome to MY. Sodium Alginate is mentioned here: https://images.shulcloud.com/395/uploads/Documents/Itemswhichdonotrequirecertification2.pdf. Follow the rules of the site and use this as a springboard for your own research rather than a psak :)

Comment: Calcium Lactate: https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/close-but-not-quite-the-same/

Answer (score 0):

[Kosherquest](https://kosherquest.org/is-it-kosher/food-additives/) says:

> Alginates – Source: seaweed. Forms: calcium alginate, alginic acid,
> sodium alginate, propylene glycol aginate. Uses: thickening and
> stabilizing agent in pastry, jelly, ice cream, cheese, candy, yogurt,
> canned frosting, whipped cream, and beer. **Kosher, pareve without
> supervision.**

[OUKosher](https://oukosher.org/blog/consumer-kosher/close-but-not-quite-the-same/) says

**calcium lactate is thus pareve.**

The site does not say whether it needs supervision – but it does not need supervision to take it out of being cholov akum.

Comment: Calcium lactate isn't dairy and thus has nothing to do with being chalav akum or chalav yisroel